# Creating User With IdentityServer4 in ASP.NET Core Chat app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, identityserver4

1. I have a project which is my IdentityServer4 Authority with separate database. It handles sing-(up,in,out) for user. Sign up requires providing some info (only matters that there are some, let it be username and profile picture).
2. I have second project which is basically API for chats. Chat object includes information about user (I want to see username and profile picture of companion when I query chat object). So, there's a problem: all info about users in isolated database and I can't access it. Basically, my API don't know about new user even if he was created via IdentityServer4. In that case there are so many problems, like I can't create chat with that user, because I'm doing that through API and user doesn't exist for it.

Should I maybe merge my IdentityServer4 and API project and their databases into one and have single dbContext and then I'll be able to properly build my chat objects? But It doesn't seem like a good idea...

I also thought about approach where Auth Server notifies API about new user and then API writes about it in his database, but I think it's not the best idea, because my API can go down and all users that registered won't be recognized by API.

There should be some atomic approach or at least the most reliable.

How can I properly handle user registration in that case?